# pyspark: upload spark-streaming dictionary output to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am parsing logs using Kafka to Spark-Streaming. I have a function that output a single log into a dictionary so that i can upload to mongoDB. However it kept promptng me an error like this:

```
8 ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp
 dir: C:\Users\siyang\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-660e59cc-6331-4ed1-b932-ca64f9a1b
8bd
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\Users\siyang\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-
660e59cc-6331-4ed1-b932-ca64f9a1b8bd
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:1031)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$m
cV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$m
cV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimize
d.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Shu
tdownHookManager.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala
:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$ano
nfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at......
```

Below is the code. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext  
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils


# MongoDB
# ----------------------------------------
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['ws-database']
collectionNm = 'ws'
collection = db[collectionNm]


# Spark Streaming
# ----------------------------------------
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")  
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1) # listen every 1 second

spark = SparkSession(sc)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc=ssc, zkQuorum='192.168.0.xxx:2181', groupId='m1', topics={'name':1}) 


def parsing(log):
    dict = {}

    # split message by line break
    log = log[1].split('\n')
    for line in log:
        if line.find('=') > 0
            words = line.split("=")
            hash = words[0]
            value = words[1].strip().replace('"',"")
            hash = hash.strip()
            dict[hash] = value

    # upload to mongodb 
    collection.insert_one(dict)


parsed = kafkaStream.map(parsing)
parsed.pprint()


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Any one has any idea what is going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map is a transformation action on your DStream.  You want to use foreachRDD which is the generic output operation for each RDD created by the stream.  The code would look something like this:

```
def sendRecord(partition):
   client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
   db = client['ws-database']
   collectionNm = 'ws'
   collection = db[collectionNm]

   for line in partition:
       // parsing step
       collection.insert_one(dict)

   client.close()


kafkaStream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(sendRecord))
kafkaStream.pprint()
```